# Converting objects from CSV into datetime

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I've got an imported csv file which has multiple columns with dates in the format "5 Jan 2001 10:20". (Note not zero-padded day)

if I do `df.dtype` then it shows the columns as being a objects rather than a string or a datetime. I need to be able to subtract 2 column values to work out the difference so I'm trying to get them into a state where I can do that.

At the moment if I try the test subtraction at the end I get the error `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`.

I've tried multiple methods but have run into a problem every way I've tried.
Any help would be appreciated. If I need to give any more information then I will.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.to_datetime()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was to do with missing values within the column. Using `coerce=True` so `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], coerce=True)` solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @MaxU, you can use `pd.to_datetime()` method to bring the values of the given column to the 'appropriate' format, like this:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
```

You would have to do this on whatever columns you have that you need trasformed to the right dtype.

Alternatively, you can use `parse_dates` argument of `pd.read_csv()` method, like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates=[1,2,3])
```

where columns 1,2,3 are expected to contain data that can be interpreted as dates.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

convert a column to datetime using this approach

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
```

If column has empty values then change error level to coerce to ignore errors: [Details](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], errors='coerce')
```

After which you should be able to subtract two dates.

example:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['to','fr','ans'])
df.to = [pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-24 13:03:12.050000'), pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-27 11:57:18.240000'), pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-23 10:07:47.660000')]
df.fr = [pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-26 23:41:21.870000'), pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-27 15:38:22.540000'), pandas.Timestamp('2014-01-23 18:50:41.420000')]
(df.fr-df.to).astype('timedelta64[h]')
```

consult this answer for more details:

[Calculate Pandas DataFrame Time Difference Between Two Columns in Hours and Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu)

If you want to directly load the column as datetime object while reading from csv, consider this example :

[Pandas read csv dateint columns to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327626/pandas-read-csv-dateint-columns-to-datetime)

Comment: This is the error I get `local variable 'mask' referenced before assignment`

Curiously, I think it is to do with the fact that I have missing values. I've found that the line works on some columns but not on ones that have NaN values.

Comment: glad i could help :) @M.Throw